# How to write data from unsigned char array that has a NULL?

Tags: c

I don't use C much so this is stumping me.

I have some data (part of a larger struct, type is `unsigned char[255]`) that I need to send over TCP/IP. I have no control over the format I get the data in.

A small sample of the data:

```
    [0] 114 'r' unsigned char
    [1] 44 ','  unsigned char
    [2] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [3] 68 'D'  unsigned char
    [4] 85 'U'  unsigned char
    [5] 255 'ÿ' unsigned char
    [6] 128 '€' unsigned char
    [7] 128 '€' unsigned char
```

The data is prefixed by some other information split by `'|'`, so my attempt is to write all the information to a buffer, also unsigned that can be sent using 3rd party software.

What the problem seems to be is that the data has `'\0'`s in it which messes with any way to write it to the buffer.

I have tried iterating the array, getting each char and attempting to `strcat` the char to the buffer, which only works for non `'\0'` character.

I have tried just `strcat` on the entire array, which also stops when it reaches the `'\0'`

So any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `memcpy_s` or `memmove_s` instead of `strcpy`, `strcat` and friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strcat` and related are *string* functions. You have an array of chars that doesn't represent a string, so you shouldn't use that family of function.

Use plain `read`/`write` calls for the network I/O. You specify the starting point and length of data to be transmitted, and the data will be sent as-is, null and all.

Use `memcpy`/`memmove` to copy things around - same thing, they don't look at the contents, just blindly copy data.

Comment: Actually, they're C-style string functions.